# How to use `apexchart` in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, apexcharts

How to use `apexchart` in Angular 7 ? Can someone implement implement it in typescript? I am searching for its typescript implementation in Angular but I am unable to do it. My Angular version is 7.2.4.

Comment: Have you tried including it in your index per the docs and creating a chart?

Comment: Yes I did that, but problem was implementing it in typescript file. I need something like @type chartjs provides. How can it be possible to user ApexChart as Type?

Comment: If there's no typings available you can [tell TS it exists](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html), but you won't get any type help.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a wrapper for Apexcharts on npm.
For more info: https://github.com/apexcharts/ng-apexcharts

Usage example: https://ngapexcharts-demo.stackblitz.io/

Comment: I tried that one, but I was not able to find code for it and on selecting BAR as chart type It was not showing any results..

Answer (score 0):

According to Apexcharts document on https://apexcharts.com/docs/installation

Firstly: you need to install package: npm i apexcharts

And again according to document you need to define ApexCharts type where you want to use as: 
`import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'`

if this works for you, go on. But if you get "...has no default export" error than you need to define as follows:
`import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js'`

Then you need a html element to bind your chart:

And finally create your chart options in proper method and render it as follows:

```
const options = {
  chart: {
    height: 300,
    type: 'line'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'sales',
    data: [30, 40, 35, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91, 125]
  }],
  xaxis: {
    categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
  }
}

const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

[Your chart will be looks like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo6mF.png)

Comment: Not working for me, is the documentation up to date?

Comment: is there a specific error message? which way did you import the library? I just now check the document for a simple html and it worked. But not sure about your angular version

Answer (score 0):

You can find proper steps to implement ApexCharts using Angular in the following link.
https://apexcharts.com/docs/angular-charts/

See this blog for detailed information to set up a project for ApexCharts and also you'll able to see one example to generate different types of charts.

[Medium Blog](https://medium.com/@darshantheerth/building-charts-with-apexcharts-and-angular-db58475fae2b).